# How to unset Cache-Control max-age in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers

I'm trying to unset Cache-Control's max-age via .htaccess. The following removes Cache-Control entirely:

```
Header unset Cache-Control
```

How do I tell it to remove just "max-age?" Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apache 2.2.4 there is a new **Header edit** action that allows you to do exactly these kind of manipulations.

From the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html): *If this request header exists, its value is transformed according to a regular expression search-and-replace. The value argument is a regular expression, and the replacement is a replacement string, which may contain backreferences.*

However, the regex needed would be fairly complicated. Hence I suggest to just use **Header set** to override the current Cache-Control *if you can hardcode the value*. Using the **set** action overrides the previous value containing max-age.